In the Intellij AWS Lambda plugin, can I set the CodeUri attribute when using the "from handler" option?
I'm trying to use the Intellij AWS Lambda plugin to locally test/debug my lambda. It's written in Go (1.22 if it matters).
I've done this before when the main() funcion is in a file at the root of my project, but now that's not possible - the main is located at /cmd/worker/main.go
When I create a template.yaml and write the AWS Serverless YAML by hand, including the CodeUri attribute I can get it to work, but that's less than ideal. That's an extra bit of code that had to be committed to the repo, and if no one else wants to use SAM, it's somewhat confusing.
(I know that seems minor, but it seems like it should be possible to config this up if a developer wants it, and ignore it otherwise).
